# using a String variable for a name of a HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I am using a while loop to read a set of commands. the command is in the following format : add item price type.
I place the types in a set of Strings, after which if the type does not exist I want to create a new hashmap containing the item(String) and the price(Double). the name of the map should be the type, but it does not allow me to use a String variable for it. Is there a way to get around that?

```
 while (!input.equals("end")){
            String[] command = input.split(" ");
            if (!categories.contains(command[3])){
                categories.add(command[3]);
                String mapName = command[3];
                Map<String, Double>  mapName = new HashMap<>();
            }
        }
```

I need the name of the map the be for example shampoos or food or whatever the input was, not mapName.

Comment: Can you give more details about " it does not allow me to use a String variable for it" ?

Comment: @MhamadElItawi it underlines it an when I place the mouse over it says the "variable is already defined in the scope"

Comment: @C.Weber I am sorry but I am unsure of what you want me to do?

Comment: @kalina199 I wanted to know the type of your variable "categories". I assume that´s the set you are talking off. I think it would be better to state what you want to achieve. I assume you are trying to group your "commands" by type. If so you have already some answers that point you in the right direction below.

Comment: @C.Weber I planned on making a set of Strings that would contain the type of the items, for example if given a command "add milk 1.2 dairy" dairy would go in the set, and then I want to create a map, called dairy and containing a key value pair- milk 1.2, I am trying to implement it with map of maps now. Commands will be add and then filter/print which I intent to omplement using stream API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't create variables dynamically in Java.

You will need to create a map of maps:

```
Map<String,Map<String,Double>> maps = new HashMap<>():

maps.put(mapName, new HashMap<>());
```

I would be very careful with using maps to store data in your program. Maps are a very bad substitute for classes.

The only case where you should use a map instead of defining a class with fixed field names is if you really don't know the values that will be input. If the input values are known it is almost always better to define classes and parse the input into the class fields.

Comment: This should also substitute for the need of making a set containing the types if I understand you correctly?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but I updated the answer. I strongly suggest you consider creating classes first to store your data rather than using maps. Only use maps if your input data is not known or does not have an easily predictable structure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am solving a problem for an online judge system and I think I am only allowed one class, excluding anonymous classes. It is oriented towards practicing maps and sets

Answer (score 2):

You will need a map of maps, where the keys of the outter map are the *names* of the inner maps, like:

```java
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> maps = new HashMap<>();

while (!input.equals("end")){
    String[] command = input.split(" ");
    if (!categories.contains(command[3])){
        categories.add(command[3]);
        String mapName = command[3];
        Map<String, Double>  map = new HashMap<>();
        maps.put(mapName, map);
    }
}
```

then you can later get the maps by using their *name* like:

```java
maps.get(<map name>)
```

Comment: I want to use the String that the variable commandName contains as a name of my Map. I need a map called dairy for example, not a Map called commandName,  I just do not know if it is possible and  how to implement it

Comment: I was not able to make the names of the inner maps to be the same as the key - it is always "map" but it works being referent type. That was my initial issue, how to assign a name that I get from somewhere and it is not hardcoded.